# neo4j order by optional property in descdending order with nulls being at the bottom

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I need to sort nodes by `createdAt` timestamp in descending order. It is an optional parameter. There are old nodes that don't have this parameter. When I try sorting as suggested in [neo4j doc](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/order-by/#order-null):

```
MATCH (node:MyTag)
WHERE ...
RETURN node
ORDER BY node.createdAt DESC
```

I get nodes where `createAt` does not exist before the ones where it exists. How can I get nodes that have createdAt in descending order first and then have the nodes that don't have createAt field?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You could add a field to your RETURN

```
COALESCE ( node.createdAt, 999999999) AS sortField
```

that would give you a value to sort on.

Comment: We are not sure that 999999999 is big enough to be at the end of the sorting. Isn't? That timestamp value in datetime is Sep 9 2001 GMT.

Comment: Well.. the idea does not depend on the exact value. The idea is to use a column that has a predictable value instead of nulls, so your can influence the order.

Comment: Noted on giving the idea. Not giving a 100% correct answer is not ideal.

Comment: ended up going with `COALESCE ( node.createdAt, 0) AS sortField`

Comment: Good. I think that validates my answer ;)